# Mapping VirtualKey to char in UWP app, independent of layout

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, uwp

I'm writing a VNC client for HoloLens using C# and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to handle keyboard input.  KeyUp/KeyDown give me a Windows.System.VirtualKey object, but there doesn't appear to be an API to map these VirtualKeys (along with modifiers, e.g. shift) to the characters they represent on a given layout.  E.g. VirtualKey.Shift + VirtualKey.F == 'F' versus 'f' when it's simply VirtualKey.F.  Or Shift + 5 to give % on a US keyboard.

In win32 apps you'd use MapVirtualKey to handle the keyboard layout for you -- how does this get handled in UWP?

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to get the translated character in KeyUp/KeyDown events. But it is possible when using [CoreWindow.CharacterReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396) event to get the translated character.

You can register the event by the following codes:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;
```

And you will get a KeyCode of the translated input character(e.g. for `shift+5` it gets `37`, while for `5` it gets `53`) through the [CharacterReceivedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.characterreceivedeventargs.aspx):

```
private void CoreWindow_CharacterReceived(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    uint keyCode=args.KeyCode;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the downside with this method is that you can't possibly get any non-character keys, and there's no way in KeyDown/KeyUp to tell what is and isn't a normal character.  Pretty much shoots the whole thing.  I ended up creating my own layout mapper to handle this.

Comment: Did you write your own layout mapper? I'm very interested in it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I didn't. You can find a custom keyboard layout demo [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/UWP-Custom-On-Screen-8fd8415e).

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT: Link is broken.   Can you update?

Comment: @baskren I think it is here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/DigitalSign
KeyAssignmentSet.cs contains mappings for custom vitrual keyboard.

Comment: @baskren here is updated version https://github.com/michaelosthege/TCD.Controls.Keyboard